# MATE: Tile 2 windows next to each other

Tags: window-manager, window, mate-desktop

I would be interested in a keyboard short-cut that would tile windows next to each other.

I would be OK with the minimal functionality: If there are exactly 2 windows in the current desktop, tile them. Of course, a script doing it is enough since it can be easily mapped to a keyboard short-cut. I checked e.g. BlueTile, but it doesn't seem to aim at this minimal requirement (it is too heavy artillery and seems not to speak with MATE at all.

Ideas how to detect all windows on current desktop, and how to resize windows from scripts would be enough for me, I can then code the final script myself.

Answer (score 2):

Detecting windows on the current desktop, and resizing them can both be done using `wmctrl`

To list all the windows you can use:

```
wmctrl -l
```

A quick example to resize the current active window to a size of 500 x 500 at position 0 0 would be:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,0,500,500
```

Finally, if you want to get the current screen size to help with your tiling script, it is provided in the output of `xdpyinfo`